# How to close tabris application

Tags: tabris

Is it possible to minimize or close tabris application (client side) ?
I wanna accomplish the same behavior that is implement on hardware control. (back button on top level page or home button) but I wanna invoke this when a certain criteria in my app is satisfied.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

On ios you can not close an application. On Android closing the last open shell (eg by pressing the back button or programmatic) also closes the app.